# spring-security4.2 Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I get exception in my spring-security xml.
[exception img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1BsA.png). 
the Exception message:
**Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Factory bean 'org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpConfigurationBuilder$SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilterBeanFactory' not found
- Factory bean 'org.springframework.security.config.http.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser$DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandlerBeanFactory' not found**
 The exception message is in Eslipse xml Editor.

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  >
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="authenticated" />
    <custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" />
    <form-login login-page="/main/login.do" 
    login-processing-url="/main/j_spring_security_check" 
    default-target-url="/attraction/list.do"
    authentication-failure-url="/main/login.do" />
    <logout logout-url="/main/logout.do" logout-success-url="/main/login.do" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"  />
     <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource" token-validity-seconds="1209600"  remember-me-parameter="remember-me" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/main/login.do">
    <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>
    <csrf disabled="true" />
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>
</security:http>
```

and I can find the class in spring-security-config.jar.
How can I  resolve the exception?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 导入java ee jar 包 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring集成memcache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cache</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmemcached-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>x-pack-transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20171018</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mybatis核心包 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- mybatis/spring包 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 导入Mysql数据库链接jar包 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 导入dbcp的jar包，用来在applicationContext.xml中配置数据库 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aliyun.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>aliyun-sdk-oss</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/soap/soap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>soap</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/axis/axis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/saaj-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsdl4j/wsdl4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core ->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Post the code of your spring security configuration and all relevant classes.

Comment: Add your dependencies to your question.

Comment: The project can run on tomcat,but eclipse xml editor has the problem.